# ! LaTeX Error: Command \textdegree unavailable in encoding OT1

Tags: symbols, natbib

### Solution found

Use of `\usepackage{textcomp}` allows for `\textdegree` macro, thanks to @Mico.

---

I use TeXmaker as an editor and I use Mendeley to generate my `.bib` file. One entry has a degree symbol in the title. Mendeley encodes into UTF-8 and I therefore use

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

however the degree symbols do not seem to work. I have also tried including

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

as per some suggestions on the stackexchange and the error changes from OT1 to T1.

How can I get the degree symbol to work?
Thanks.

---

Edit - MWE (which causes the error):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

% Text and Maths
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                                 % Input accented characters from keyboard input


%References and page interlinking

\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress,super]{natbib}        % References - [numbers,sort&compress,super]
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}                                   % BibStyle - unsrt keeps 1,2,3 instead of 2,1,3 (?)

\usepackage[final]{hyperref}                                    % adds hyper links inside the generated pdf file
\hypersetup{
colorlinks=true,                                                    % false: boxed links; true: colored links
linkcolor=blue,                                                     % color of internal links
citecolor=blue,                                                     % color of links to bibliography
filecolor=magenta,                                              % color of file links
urlcolor=blue                                                       % colour of url link
}
\usepackage{cleveref}                                               % Clever ref - loaded AFTER hyperref!

\begin{document}

test
\citep{Zimmermann2009}

\bibliography{/Users/me/Documents/library.bib}
\end{document}
```

`.bib` entry, error caused by degree symbol in title, I believe.

```
@article{Zimmermann2009,
abstract = {An unusual variety of magnetic, magnetoelectric and ferrotoroidic properties was observed in the lithium-orthophosphates LiMPO(4) with M = Fe, Co, Ni by optical second harmonic generation. In spite of a largely similar magnetic and crystallographic structure the compounds exhibit pronounced differences in the topology of antiferromagnetic 180A degrees domains. In LiCoPO(4) the antiferromagnetic domains coexist with ferrotoroidic, i.e., magnetic vortex domains. For LiNiPO(4) it was shown that the weak ferrimagnetic moment of the LiMPO(4) compounds along the spin direction is rigidly coupled to the AFM order parameter so that the sign of the magnetoelectric effect is reversed by a magnetic field only. Further effects of a static magnetic field on the system are discussed.},
author = {Zimmermann, A. S. and {Van Aken}, B. B. and Schmid, H. and Rivera, J. P. and Li, J. and Vaknin, D. and Fiebig, M.},
doi = {10.1140/epjb/e2009-00223-3},
file = {:Users/matt/Documents/Mendeley Desktop/Zimmermann et al. - 2009 - Anisotropy of antiferromagnetic 180° domains in magnetoelectric LiMPO 4 (M = Fe, Co, Ni).pdf:pdf},
isbn = {1434-6028},
issn = {14346028},
journal = {European Physical Journal B},
number = {3},
pages = {355--360},
title = {{Anisotropy of antiferromagnetic 180° domains in magnetoelectric LiMPO 4 (M = Fe, Co, Ni)}},
volume = {71},
year = {2009}
}
```

Comment: I suggest you use `biblatex` and `biber` if you're allowed to. `Bibtex` doesn't understand `utf8` encoding.

Comment: Could you possibly show us an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) of your problem? We would need to know how exactly the degree symbol is included and processed in your document.

Comment: Also the `Zimmermann2009` entry is needed.

Comment: Please show us the bib entry `Zimmermann2009`. (I assume it contains a `textdegree` directive; is that right?) A separate suggestion: Since you're using the `natbib` citation management package, you may want to switch bibliography styles from `unsrt` to `unsrtnat`.

Comment: I've added a MWE which causes the error

Comment: @Bernard, how would I change it, as it is apparently Bib(la)tex in the preferences for Texmaker

Comment: I get a different error: `Unicode char ° (U+B0) not set up for use with LaTeX.`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to keep using the `natbib` package and the `unsrt` bibliography style, all you need to do is (a) replace the symbol `°` in the `title` field with "`\textdegree\`" and (b) load the `textcomp` package, as it provides the macro `textdegree`.

The following code should compile just fine. (I've simplified the bib entry by deleting fields that are disregarded by the `unsrt` bibliography style.)

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mylibrary.bib}
@article{Zimmermann2009,
  author  = {Zimmermann, A. S. and Van Aken, B. B. and
            Schmid, H. and Rivera, J. P. and Li, J. and 
            Vaknin, D. and Fiebig, M.},
  journal = {European Physical Journal B},
  number  = {3},
  pages   = {355--360},
  title   = {{Anisotropy of antiferromagnetic 180\textdegree\ domains
            in magnetoelectric LiMPO~4 (M=Fe, Co, Ni)}},
  volume  = {71},
  year    = {2009}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}% for '\textdegree' macro
\usepackage[sort&compress,super]{natbib} % no need to specify "numbers"
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\usepackage{hyperref}                                   
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta, urlcolor=blue}
\usepackage{cleveref}  

\begin{document}
test\citep{Zimmermann2009}
\bibliography{mylibrary}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: Instead of using pdfLaTeX with the `fontenc`, `inputenc`, and `textcomp` packages, you may want to look into using LuaLaTeX along with the `fontspec` package. If you can make this switch, you'll have native support for utf8-encode symbols.

[image]

```
% !TeX program = lualatex

\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mylibrary.bib}
@article{Zimmermann2009,
abstract= {An unusual variety of magnetic, magnetoelectric and ferrotoroidic properties was observed in the lithium-orthophosphates LiMPO(4) with M = Fe, Co, Ni by optical second harmonic generation. In spite of a largely similar magnetic and crystallographic structure the compounds exhibit pronounced differences in the topology of antiferromagnetic 180A degrees domains. In LiCoPO(4) the antiferromagnetic domains coexist with ferrotoroidic, i.e., magnetic vortex domains. For LiNiPO(4) it was shown that the weak ferrimagnetic moment of the LiMPO(4) compounds along the spin direction is rigidly coupled to the AFM order parameter so that the sign of the magnetoelectric effect is reversed by a magnetic field only. Further effects of a static magnetic field on the system are discussed.},
author  = {Zimmermann, A. S. and {Van Aken}, B. B. and Schmid, H. and Rivera, J. P. and Li, J. and Vaknin, D. and Fiebig, M.},
doi     = {10.1140/epjb/e2009-00223-3},
file    = {:Users/mcolbear/Documents/Mendeley Desktop/Zimmermann et al. - 2009 - Anisotropy of antiferromagnetic 180° domains in magnetoelectric LiMPO 4 (M = Fe, Co, Ni).pdf:pdf},
isbn    = {1434-6028},
issn    = {14346028},
journal = {European Physical Journal~B},
number  = {3},
pages   = {355--360},
title   = {{Anisotropy of antiferromagnetic 180° domains in magnetoelectric LiMPO~4 (M = Fe, Co, Ni)}},
volume  = {71},
year    = {2009}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec} % don't load 'inputenc', 'fontenc', & 'textcomp' packages
\usepackage[sort&compress,super]{natbib} % no need to specify "numbers" option
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\usepackage{hyperref}                                   
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta, urlcolor=blue}
\usepackage{cleveref}  

\begin{document}
test\citep{Zimmermann2009}
\bibliography{mylibrary}
\end{document}
```

Comment: My problem is that Mendeley will overwrite the file and revert any changes I make to the file. However, adding in the textcomp package has resolved the issue. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Matt - If you have a lot of utf8-encoded special symbols in your files, it may be worth switching from pdfLaTeX to LuaLaTeX (or XeLaTeX). I've posted an addendum to show how such a switch can be accomplished.